# Can't use Flyout in the Button in WinRT?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

While using the Flyout in the Button as mentioned in the below code snippet,

```
  <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Open Flyout">
     <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout>
           //some code
         </Flyout>
      </Button.Flyout>
   </Button>
```

It throws the following errors while building the app:

1. Unknown type 'Flyout' in XML namespace
   http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
2. Unknown member 'Flyout' on element 'Button'

**Note :** It worked fine previously (a month before)

Vs2012 - Windows8.1

What am i missing? any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Joy Oyiess Rex K

Comment: When i create a blank app and add <Button>
            <Button.Flyout>
                <Flyout></Flyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>, it's work well.

Comment: @MatDev8 as mentioned earlier it worked fine previously, but not now. Yes i have checked with the code snippet as you have mentioned in your previous comment, but that too not works for me. Can u check with the following scenario (Vs2012 with Windows8.1)

Answer (score 0):

The Flyout is a new control in Windows 8.1. You need Visual Studio 2013 to develop apps for Windows 8.1.

Comment: is it so? is there such issues with between VS versions?@cremor

Comment: @JOYOYIESSREX Officially, you need VS 2012 to target 8.0 and VS 2013 to target 8.1. Maybe there are hacks to get it working anyway, but I don't know about that.